# SQLiteDatabase need help in query... please

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this table:

```
id | CUPNAME | FRENCHNAME
1  | 2       | null
2  | null    | 4
```

I want to pull data from CUPNAME and FRENCHNAME which is not null.
The table can be filled with numbers from 1 to 10. In this example, should be able to CUPNAME=2, FRENCHNAME = 4.

there is such a query:

```
SELECT sum(ifnull(french_press_bd.CUPNAME,0)) as a , sum(ifnull(french_press_bd.FRENCHNAME,0)) as b FROM my_table WHERE id in (1,2)
```

I try to write so it does not work:

```
 String sqr = "id in (1,2)";
Cursor cursor = sqdb.query(french_press_bd.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {                   
"sum(ifnull(french_press_bd.CUPNAME,0)) as a , sum(ifnull(french_press_bd.FRENCHNAME,0)) as b" 
},sqr, null,null,null,null );
```

Comment: You need to give two strings (one for each column), but what do you actually want?

Comment: I want to bring in one line data from a table, removing values null

Comment: Please edit your question to show the input table and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use rawQuery. As:

```
String your_query= "SELECT sum(ifnull(french_press_bd.CUPNAME,0)) as a , sum(ifnull(french_press_bd.FRENCHNAME,0)) as b FROM my_table WHERE id in (1,2)";
Cursor result = sqdb.rawQuery(your_query, null);
```

But make sure that `SQLiteDatabase` is not `NULL`. You have to call before it,

```
sqdb = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase(); // or getWritableDatabase()
```

Comment: oh thanks for the tip but apparently I did not properly create the query.
I have a table with two columns and TSUPNAME TSUPNAME and two rows value in the first row CUPNAME = 1 = FRENCHNAME null
value in the second row CUPNAME = null FRENCHNAME = 2
I wanted to get to the log values ​​in a way "12" and get rid of null

Comment: @user2923449 You should have specified this requirement in OP!

Answer (score 0):

This query uses two scalar subqueries to get the first non-NULL value from the respective column:

```
SELECT (SELECT CUPNAME
        FROM my_table
        WHERE id IN (1, 2)
          AND CUPNAME IS NOT NULL
       ) AS CUPNAME,
       (SELECT FRENCHNAME
        FROM my_table
        WHERE id IN (1, 2)
          AND FRENCHNAME IS NOT NULL
       ) AS FRENCHNAME;
```

Since the outer query doesn't actually do anything, it might be simpler just to execute the two queries individually:

```java
long cName = db.compileStatement("SELECT CUPNAME FROM my_table" +
                                 " WHERE id IN (1, 2) AND CUPNAME IS NOT NULL"
                                ).simpleQueryForLong();
long fName = db.compileStatement("SELECT FRENCHNAME FROM my_table" +
                                 " WHERE id IN (1, 2) AND FRENCHNAME IS NOT NULL"
                                ).simpleQueryForLong();
```

Comment: I do not understand your question.